# Find writable files in Mac OS

Tags: linux, macos, find

I want to find (recursively) writable files in my directory. My operating system is MacOS.

I tried:

```
find . -type  -writable
```

but the shell returns an error:

> find: -type: -writable: unknown type

Why I got the error? Are there alternatives?

Comment: try just find -writable

Comment: @RachelGallen did not work, have tried it already. Same error.

Comment: The type `-writable` does NOT exist in your `find` command. See `man find`. @Thor shows your several ways to find writable files, depending on who they should be writable by (ugo, in a nutshell, is for: user? group of the user? or any other?). Launch his command with the right user, and with the right -perm .....  to look exactly what you want to try to look for. You can tell us what you need to find out (**which user**'s files should not be writable **by which user(s)**), and we'll give you the ..... perm you should look for. examples: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/blcmdl1_findx.htm

Comment: Options "-writable" and "-readable" are probably linux only:  Beware! Always try to learn (and stick to) the portable ways... and beware of webpages that don't tell when giving non-portable options. a find with an -exec rm with the wrong (non portable) optinos could be deadly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writable by whom?

If you mean writable by any, you can use:

```
find . -type f -perm -0222
```

or

```
find . -type f -perm -ugo=w
```

If you mean writable by `other`, use:

```
find . -type f -perm -0002
```

or

```
find . -type f -perm -o=w
```